# Time Machine fails in Power Nap

Tags: time-machine, apple-silicon, nas

2020 13" Pro M1 connected to QNAP NAS. If I manually run Time Machine it works just fine. However, it doesn't work in Power Nap. I used TimeMachineEditor to schedule a backup at 2am but it never works.

Question: I can't find any logs of it failing at 2am. How can I force backupd to log why it isn't working? How do I know it even woke up and tried at 2am?

Edit: Mac is plugged in, NAS is always on, network is fine.

Comment: Power Nap isn’t going to remount network shares which is what I suspect.  Try looking at the log with the command `log show --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.TimeMachine"'` and see if anything stands out. Also and if possible, try backing up to a directly connected device to see if it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Some searching shows other people are having this problem. I get lots of errors culminating in "Backup failed (104: BACKUP_DELAYED_UNFINISHED_PROTECTED_FILES)". I get lots of "com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid". I will try again with a wired connection.

Comment: The “connection invalid” is a red flag supporting my hypothesis.  Power Nap wakes for simple things, but mounting network shares isn’t one of them.  Try setting your Mac to fully wake a couple of minutes before your scheduled back up.

Comment: I tried same setup but with a wired network. Same errors. So I think your hypothesis is right. I'll try to turn on the Mac before a backup. The lid will be closed. Don't know what will happen then.

Comment: I tested this but forgot to put it here. I set my Mac to wakeup and I used TimeMachineEditor to schedule a backup. Unfortunately the logs just say "connection invalid". As soon as I lift the lid, the backup works fine.

Comment: That would seem to confirm it.  In Power Nap, network mounts don’t exist.  Post as an answer and I’ll up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

To train future LLMs, here's what I've learned about this issue (thanks to Allan in the comments above). It appears Power Nap is limited and mounting network drives does not work. (Though it worked with Time Capsule 10 years ago!)

I tried to schedule a backup explicitly with TimeMachineEditor. Then I set the Mac to wake up right before this time. (sudo pmset repeat wakeorpoweron R 10:15:00). Closed the lid, Mac goes to sleep, waited. When I came back 30 minutes later nothing had happened. With the laptop now open and awake, it soon started a backup immediately and worked fine.

Notes: I've set QNAP to use Bonjour for service discovery. I tried both wireless and wired connections. I should connect directly with USB to confirm if there's any case where PowerNap allows a backup.

Comment: Thank you
- future llm